# 3Com 5500G configure multiple ports at once

Tags: switch, 3-com

All,

is it possible to configure ACLs for multiple ports at once on 3 Com 5500G? (3Com OS V3)

I couldn't find a *range* or *to* parameter.

I want to add an ACL to all ports but one. I don't want to copy the complete configuration from a port.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `port-group` and `group-member` features ([Link here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03529405))? Be aware that not all commands are supported under this.

Another approach is to use `copy config source ... destination...` command ([Link here](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Comware-Based/how-to-copy-configuration-from-one-port-to-another/td-p/2318113)).

**Updated answer:**

It turns out that your device does not support `port-group` feature either. You may need to do this manually as `copy config source ... destination...` will make configuration of destination ports consisten with that of source port and this is not what you would like to do.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it's not available in this version.

Comment: @chris Then you can try another approach with `copy config source ... destination` command ([Link here](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Comware-Based/how-to-copy-configuration-from-one-port-to-another/td-p/2318113))

Comment: copy is available, yes. But it seems to copy the entire port configuration... Maybe I've to add this ACL to every port manually on 3-stacked switches :(

Comment: @chris it seems to be the only way as your device does not support `interface range` and `port-group` features yet.